# Sharing across view in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, view, share

I have a project where users are assgned to a client and I wannt to share that info across views.

In AppServiceProvider I added

```
use View;
use Auth;
```

and then amended boot to

```
if ( Auth::check() )
            {
                $cid = Auth::user()->client_id;
                $company = \App\Clients::first($cid);
                view::share('company',$company);
            }
```

but if I dd($company) I get

```
Undefined variable: company
```

Comment: could it be a typo? view is not View (first letter capitalized)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because of the `Auth` is not working in `AppServiceProvider`

So your If condition return `false`

if you share data with all the views then your code like this without check Auth. then It will work.

```
$company = 'Some value';
view::share('company',$company);

dd($company);     // for print output.
```

Solution - For Alternate option you have to make `Helper` class.

Answer (score 1):

At the time the providers `boot` is run, the Auth guard has not been booted, so `Auth::check()` returns false, and `Auth::user()` returns null.

You could do the `View::share` in a middleware, or perhaps in the constructor of a controller (the base controller to share it across the whole application, or some particular controller if you need it in some subset of routes).